# Comparing scattering parameters in dB and magnitude+angle forms

Tags: s-parameters, units

We're trying to compare the scattering parameters from two parts ([ADG902](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG901_902.pdf) and [BF1101](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/BF1101_R_WR.pdf)). Their datasheets use dB and mag/angle respectively.

**ADG902:**
[image: ADG902 Datasheet]

**BF1101:**
[image: BF1101 Datasheet]

When trying to convert between the two, we aren't getting numbers that make sense. For example, converting the S<sub>11</sub> parameter at 1000 MHz, 0.832, to dB (using dB = 20·log<sub>10</sub>(mag)), we get -1.59 dB which is way off from the 28 dB of the ADG902. Are we missing something in these conversions?

Comment: Your calculation is correct, both parts have indeed a very different return loss. The reason is that you are comparing very different parts with each other. The switch is already matched internally to 50 Ohm as it doesn't require additional parts outside this IC. On the other hand, the BF1101 is just a single transistor that needs additional parts around it (e.g. for setting its operating point). In such cases you need to design your own impedance matching network.

Comment: The 902 is a switch being measured as a switch, and the 1101 is a FET being measured as an amplifier. The high S11 of the FET is because the gate is a high impedance, mostly capacitance.